# read text in userform label and add to worksheet

Tags: excel, label, userform, vba

This is my first time posting, so please let me know if I've screwed up on any of the forum etiquette!

I have a userform which contains a label, two combo boxes and button. The text for the label is set in a sub and is text describing a game. I am asking the user to select the two umpires who umpired this game from the two combo boxes. The button is "next game" button. When the user clicks the "next game" button I match the two umpires to a list of names on the "Umpires" worksheet. I then want to be able to use the text in the label (which says which game it is) and paste it in the first vacant row adjacent to the umpires' names. The code is on the "click button" event of the "next game" button. I am currently getting run-time error '1004'.

```
Private Sub nextGameBtn_Click()

Dim ump1 As String
Dim ump2 As String
Dim endRow As Long
Dim ump1Row As Range
Dim ump2Row As Range
Dim ump1EndColumn As Long
Dim ump2EndColumn As Long
Dim game As String

ump1 = selectUmpsForm.ComboBox1.Value
ump2 = selectUmpsForm.ComboBox2.Value

endRow = Worksheets("Umpires").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


Set ump1Row = Worksheets("Umpires").Range("A2:A" & endRow).Find(What:=ump1, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

ump1EndColumn = Worksheets("Umpires").Range("IV" & ump1Row.Row).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1


Set ump2Row = Worksheets("Umpires").Range("A2:A" & endRow).Find(What:=ump2, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

ump2EndColumn = Worksheets("Umpires").Range("IV" & ump2Row.Row).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1

game = selectUmpsForm.lblGame.Caption

Worksheets("Umpires").Range(Cells(ump1Row.Row, ump1EndColumn), Cells(ump2Row.Row, ump2EndColumn)).Value = game


gameCount = gameCount + 1
Call displayBox(gameCount)

End Sub
```

The run-time error occurs on the line:

```
Worksheets("Umpires").Range(Cells(ump1Row.Row, ump1EndColumn), Cells(ump2Row.Row, ump2EndColumn)).Value = game
```

If there a away I can read the label text without having to go back to the source which created it? Is this the reason for my run-time error?

Any advise would be appreciated.
Cheers
Im

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's related to the label. Run-time error 1004 could happen when one of the values in Cells() is zero.

Have you checked the values of ump2EndColumn etc.? Did you make sure none of the cells you're trying to write to are write-protected?

Try step-by-step debugging with F8, and try to simplify the statement to isolate the error, for example

```
Worksheets("Umpires").Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(3, 3)).Value = game
Worksheets("Umpires").Range(Cells(ump1Row.Row, ump1EndColumn), Cells(ump2Row.Row, ump2EndColumn)).Value = "test"
```

etc.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Daniel, 
thanks for advice re step by step debugging and simplifying things - it's help me find the error!
My game variable is reading the label fine, as you thought.

My row and column references are all fine, it seems to be a problem with the Range part ... if I put Range("B2") it works fine, but I get the error trying to refer to the cell(s) in any other way.

PS does that I mean I need to re-tag my question, or even close this one and repost??? 

Thanks so much :-)